# Find and replace with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I am trying to grep column 4 with pipe delimiter (`|`) and replace all double quotes within it and then enclose that string with double quotes again.

sample File:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9
value1|value2|value3|"|||||value"4|value5|value6|"||value"7|value8|value9
```

Problem is column 4 is where user can write anything, even a pipe, which is my delimiter and it breaks my process.

E.g. column 4 may be

```
"|||||value"4
```

Now I am trying to write command which goes to column 4, replace all double quotes then enclose it with double quote again so I can treat it as single string to make my process work.

Required Output for column 4 is

```
"|||||value4"
```

Similarly I have do the same for column 7, required Output for column 7 is

```
"||value7"
```

Final output should look like this:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9
value1|value2|value3|"|||||value4"|value5|value6|"||value7"|value8|value9
```

please suggest.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Please mention that in the question instead of using tags for it (OS tags should be used when the question is about the OS, not when you're simply using that OS). And you have tagged with both Linux and Solaris, two very different systems with different versions of the standard tools.

Comment: In addition to what terdon said, you have tagged the question with both `awk` and `sed`, but thu only utility mentioned in the question itself is `grep`.

Comment: I have to implement it on both Linux and Solaris OS using awk cmd.

Comment: For properly formatted CSV, you should double any existing double quotes, then enclose in double quotes: `test|test_f|21/03/2017|"""|||||USER ""RIGHTa anything here"|123`

Comment: And you should be fixing the process that creates the file in the first place, instead of repairing the damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **`sed`** assuming you only have 5 columns and the column which should be quoted is column4 in your case:

```
sed -E 's/"//g; s/^(([^|]*\|){3})(.*)(\|[^|]*)$/\1"\3"\4/' infile
```

This will work even if no quotes entered by user, if entered any quotes by user or pipes.

Here is an **`awk`** solution too as requested:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{ for (i=1; i<NF; i++){if (i>3)gsub("\"",""); 
  printf (i!=(NF-1))?$i"|"((i==3)?"\"":""):$i"\"|"}; print $NF}' infile

col1|col2|col3|"col4"|col5
test|test_f|21/03/2017|"|||||USER RIGHTa anything here"|123
```

Comment: -Thanks this works like a charm. Ran into another problem where I have 2 faulty columns and count from end of the line fails(NF-1).

Comment: column4 is your column(NF-1) already!

Comment: @αғsнιη-Thanks this works like a charm. Ran into another problem where I have 2 faulty columns and count from end of the line fails(NF-1).

col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9
test|test_f|21/03/2017|"|||||USER "RIGHTa anything "here|123|erer|""||User Comments|test|test23

Here is problem with col4 :
"|||||USER "RIGHTa anything "here

and col7 :
""||User Comments

Comment: still you didn't edit into your question with [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433268/find-and-replace-with-awk/433280?noredirect=1#comment782479_433280), since I cannot recognize where is the next line starts.

Comment: I have edited my question, thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I should say that it's not possible to fix your broken file with this way since the broken column is in middle of the line, you need go and fix the process creating this file first.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvformat -d '|' -D '|' file.csv
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5
test|test_f|21/03/2017|"|||||USER RIGHTa anything here"|123
```

The `-d` and `-D` flags define the delimiter used in the input and output respectively.

Comment: hmm, still I cannot recognize how double quote moved out of string!

Comment: @αғsнιη Double quotes are the default quoting characters for CSV files. The whole field does not need to be quoted, but the delimiters that are part of the data needs to be. CSVkit's `csvformat` is able to read the partially quoted field and outputs it fully quoted. One may also choose to _escape_ the delimiters in the field with `-U 3 -P '\'` (for backslash escapes, `-U 3` means "no quotes").

Comment: @αғsнιη If the user was using a CSV-aware parser in his workflow, this transformation would not be needed.

Comment: OK, thanks, now in OP's question,  user fortunately entered two double quotes `"|||||USER "RIGHTa anything here`, what if user only input `|||||USER RIGHTa anything here` or `"|||||"USER "RIGHTa anything here` or some varied string? does this tool `csvformat` can print the same and result with `"|||||USER RIGHTa anything here"`? Where OP is asked to remove quotes and quote whole column 4 again.

Comment: @αғsнιη No. In those cases, the quoting is broken, and if the program that writes the data to the CSV file does not insert any other form of quoting characters around the string (at least around the delimiters), `csvformat` will not be able to handle the data.  You could probably solve that by parsing each row backwards with `awk` or something to "peel off" the last column.

Comment: thank you, so this solution only will work if user input quotes and with _even_ numbers of quotes, correct? or only 2 quotes?

Comment: @αғsнιη It will work as long as the delimiter characters in the data field are quoted with double quotes and as long as the double quotes are paired up properly.